# Using regex to extract values of this form

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have several files that each contain (somewhere in the file) a line that looks like:

```
Item Number(s) 010314565
```

or

```
Item Number(s) 92349252 and 30239429434
```

or

```
Item Number(s) 124029354,345340332,  234325923, 2121124
```

In other words `Item Number(s)`  followed by a list of numbers (each may start with 0) that may be "and" delimited or comma-delimited, sometimes with space between them, and not always a consistent amount of space.

Is this too heavy for Python regex or is it doable?

It's easy enough to extract all `[\d]+` from the file but I don't need every number in the entire file, just the ones that come after "Item Number(s)"
.

Or is it better to just iterate over each line of the file until I find Item Number(s) and then run a `findall` on that?

Comment: Do it in two steps. First check if the line begins with `Item Numbers(s)`, then use a regexp to extract the numbers.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a lookbehind that matches `Item Number(s)...`, but lookbehinds have to be fixed length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look for `Item Number(s)` and remove this and anything what comes before it and then search the remaining string for numbers.

```
import re
s =  "this part 123 should be ignored Item Number(s) 92349252 and 30239429434, 124029354,345340332,  234325923 2121124"
re.findall(r'.*?(\d+)', re.sub(r'.*?Item Number\(s\)', '', s))
```

result

```
['92349252', '30239429434', '124029354', '345340332', '234325923', '2121124']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, it gets all of the numbers. Without splitting them, all you need to do is either iterate over the lines and running the regex for each line. Or run it globally on the entire file, then handle the splitting with the delimeters `and` and `,`

```
import re

matches = re.findall(r"Item Number\(s\) ([\d, and]+)",stringOrLine)
```